# MX Google maps throws a "failed to open dir" php error

Tags: expressionengine

I have [MX Google Maps](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-google-maps) installed on an ExpressionEngine website.

When editing a field ( any field ) I'm greeted by this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:
>   opendir(/opt/www/old_site/themes/third_party/mx_google_map/maps-icons/):
>   failed to open dir: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: mx_google_map/ft.mx_google_map.php
>
> Line Number: 212

MX google maps tries to use the theme folder path specified in an old site.
I've used the correct theme folder path in my general configuration and global template preferences, but MX google maps seems to stick to the old path.

Do I have to change it somewhere else, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the add-on source code, it appears to be checking a setting `path_markers_icons`, and if that is blank, defaulting to the EE theme path.

You should be able to find the `path_markers_icons` setting under the global fieldtype settings (under Add-ons > Fieldtypes). I suggest you make the setting blank so that it uses the built in EE theme path and doesn't trip you up in future.

Also, going by your line number it looks like you're not running the latest version (or at least the version that I just downloaded), so I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: the path was indeed specified under the add-ons > fieldtypes settings. Removing it over there fixes the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think I've had this problem before, and I'm pretty sure Max Lazar saves the path in the database for some reason. Do a search for www/old_site/ on your DB and see if you get any results.

Cheers,

Rob

Comment: searched the DB, no results.  When looking at his code I see he uses this to set the theme folder path: $this->EE->config->item('theme_folder_path') . Any idea where I can change this value ?

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark here: did you have a look in the exp_site table and in the site_system_preferences field? To echo Rob's thoughts, I vaguely remember having problems with that one on an MSM site, albeit not with that add-on. It's base 64 encoded so use this to decode.

http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/

If your "old" theme_folder_path value in there, change it and base 64encode it to see if it changes something. Although, specifying theme_folder_path and theme_folder_url in config.php should override whatever is in the DB.